# Regex in java according to word length

Tags: regex

Currently I am given a text file and I need to remove some words according to their length. In this particular case I need to remove the words that have less than 5 characters.
These are some lines from the text file:

```
"Yellow Submarine"


In the town where I was born
 Lived a man who sailed to sea
 And he told us of his life
In the land of submarines
```

At first glance I thought this was an easy task to complete, but unfortunately I have not succeed. This is what I have done so far :

```
try{
        FileReader input= new FileReader("sub.txt");
        BufferedReader myBuffer= new BufferedReader(input);
        String c=myBuffer.readLine();
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\s[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}\\s");
        Matcher m;

        while (c!=null){
            if (c!=null){
                m=p.matcher(c);
                if (m.find()){
                    System.out.println(m.group());
                }
            }
        }

    c=myBuffer.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("It was not possible to load the file");
    }
```

Is there any about the way I am defining the regular expression or a special function could be used instead?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Less than 5 means `{1,4}`, not `{5,}` (= 5 or more). I think you need to also remove the trailing `\s`. Something like `line=line.replaceAll("(?U)\\s*\\p{L}{1,4}\\b", "")` could do, too.

Comment: Because I want to remove the words that are less than 5, my idea was to identify the words that are longer and keep them in the code, it means to get rid of the ones which are {1,4}. That why at the end I just want to print the ones that meet the condition

Comment: I see. Could you explain me what do (?U) , \\p{L} and \\b mean? Though they work I do not completely understand what they do :(

Comment: Do you really need `\\s` before and after? https://regex101.com/r/9cE9jT/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove words with less than 5 letters, you may use

```
line=line.replaceAll("(?U)\\s*\\b\\p{Alnum}{1,4}\\b", "");
```

The `.replaceAll` will remove all substrings that match the pattern:

- `(?U)` - `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` inline modifier option (embedded flag) that will make `\b` and `\p{Alnum}` Unicode aware
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (you might want to use `\\W*` to match any 0+ nbon-word chars)
- `\\b` - word boundary
- `\\p{Alnum}{1,4}` - 1 to 4 alphanumeric chars
- `\\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Wiktor. It really helped me :)

Comment: I already marked your answer as the solution I was looking for. No worries :)